# Divergent non negative series smaller than harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Yesterday I was explaining the mechanics of numeric series to a friend of mine. When I was talking about the divergence of harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ and the convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$, for all $\alpha>1$ (Dirichlet's Theorem), she asked me if the harmonic series is the smallest divergent series that exists. Of course I said **NO!** For instance, the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3n}$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}-4\right)$ are all divergent and smaller than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$.

I know that my examples are correct, but she said (with some truth on her point of view), that I was cheeting and wasn't giving her a true reflected example of what she was asking.

Well, the truth is I can't imagine a proper example to give her!

Can anyone give me one? I'm (she is) looking for a divergent non rational nor irrational series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$

**a)** of non negative terms (at least from some $n_0$);

**b)** smaller than harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$.

**c)** $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{p=1}^n\frac{1}{p}=+\infty$.

I think she will be pleased if I give her an example on the previous conditions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log n}$?

Comment: Perfect! So simple :) Just waiting to accept it!

Comment: Pspi.'Smaller' : $\sum 1/p$ where $p$ are primes diverges.